# Fixing connection with nmcli, I need to edit / remove IP4.ADDRESS[2] and IP4.GATEWAY values

Tags: networking, raspbian, nmcli

I have switched my main router and with that the IP addresses ranges from 10.x.x.x to 192.x.x.x and I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian which has old data mixed with the new data and it's causing some connection issues.

After some research around I found that in these scenarios the nmcli tool can fix it, but there's something specific I don't know how.

When running `nmcli connection show "Wired connection 1"` I get the following results (I'm omitting some lines just to keep it shorter):

```
connection.id:                          Wired connection 1
connection.uuid:                        c47d1c75-5247-34c7-869f-1baee7a13914
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.interface-name:              --
connection.type:                        802-3-ethernet
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
...
ipv4.method:                            manual
ipv4.dns:                               192.168.1.1
ipv4.dns-search:
ipv4.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         192.168.1.205/24
ipv4.gateway:                           192.168.1.1
ipv4.routes:
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
...
GENERAL.NAME:                           Wired connection 1
GENERAL.UUID:                           c47d1c75-5247-34c7-869f-1baee7a13914
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        eth0
GENERAL.STATE:                          activated
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        yes
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       no
GENERAL.VPN:                            no
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    --
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.205/24
IP4.ADDRESS[2]:                         10.0.0.18/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.0.0.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::42bd:52af:ff83:fa15/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

So you can see that:

- ipv4.addresses has the correct IP
- ipv4.gateway has the correct gateway

but then at the bottom of the file I get:

```
IP4.ADDRESS[2]:                         10.0.0.18/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.0.0.1
```

which are the old ones and I can't remove them.

If I run `nmcli con mod "Wired connection 1" -ipv4.addresses "10.0.0.18"` I get a response saying: `Error: failed to remove a value from ipv4.addresses: the property doesn't contain IP address '10.0.0.18'.` which I guess is right because it's not under the ipv4.addresses property.

How do I modify that part?

Answer (score 3):

After doing more research online, what was missing is that after modifying the connection I had to do a `nmcli connection up`. After doing that the IP4 settings updated to the new ones I set up.

The solution was here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306283